# Как работает width в css?

Tags: css

Только начал изучать `css`. Почему элементы с одинаковым параметром `width` реально имеют разную ширину? И как это исправить? У меня есть два элемента - заголовок `h2` и список `ul`. И при одинаковом значении ширины в 300px заголовок уже чем список. Это как-то связано именно со списком? Как мне сделать, чтобы они оба были одинаковой ширины (без подбора значений вручную)?

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  display: block;
}

h2 {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  border: ridge;
}

ul {
  width: 300px;
  border: ridge;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>
    Title here
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>
    TODO:
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Make front page</li>
    <li>Make new styles</li>
    <li>Create database</li>
    <li>Write some code</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: это связано с тем, что у списка есть `padding`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите сейчас. Ширина не может быть разной, если указан один параметр `width`. Но если такое происходит, то нужно искать причину. Возможно, причина в отступах `margin` или `padding`. В вашем примере указал все отступы равны ноль. Вот результат:

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  display: block;
}

h2 {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  border: ridge;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 300px;
  border: ridge;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>
    Title here
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>
    TODO:
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Make front page</li>
    <li>Make new styles</li>
    <li>Create database</li>
    <li>Write some code</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: По умолчанию у некоторых элементов есть свои margin и padding. В вашем случае у элемента ul по умолчанию стоит padding-left: 40 px; (У разных браузеров размер paddingможет быть разный )

Comment: это не для Вас :)) не туда комментарий написал :(

Answer (score 2):

Разная ширина связана с тем, что строчные теги имеют вшитые padding и margin. Пропишите в стилях к ul "padding: 0;"
Подробнее можно почитать: http://htmlbook.ru/content/vstroennye-elementy

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что по умолчанию для всех элементов `box-sizing: content-box`, [почитать](http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing)

По умолчанию `width` для элемента равняется = `padding` + `border-width` + `width`

В примере видно как он себя ведёт:

```css
div {
  width: 80px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.border-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-box {
  box-sizing: content-box; /* по умолчанию для всех элементов */
  
}
```

```html
<div class="border-box">
  Реально 80px блок
</div>
<div class="content-box">
  80width + padding20px (слева и справа по 10px) + border10px (слева и справа по 5px)
</div>
```

Я в своих проектах используя такое, чтобы задать для всех элементов `box-sizing: border-box`

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```